# Alphanumeric substitution with vim

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the vscode vimplugin. I have a bunch of lines that look like:

```
Terry,169,80,,,47,,,22,,,6,,
```

I want to remove all the alphanumeric characters after the first comma so I get:

```
Terry,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

In command mode I tried:

```
s/^.+\,[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+//g
```

But this does not appear to do anything. How can I get this working?

edit:

```
s/^[^,]\+,[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+//g
```

Comment: BTW, you have escaping wrong. It should be `^.\+,`

Comment: The flag `g` is meaningless if you anchor the regexp with the first `^`

Comment: Obligatory notice that you are not, in fact, using Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\+` is greedy; `^.\+,` eats the entire line up to the **last** `,`.

Instead of the dot (which means "any character") use `[^,]` which means "any but a comma". Then `^[^,]\+,` means "any characters up to the **first** comma".

The problem with your requirement is that you want to anchor at the beginning using `^` so you cannot use flag `g` — with the anchor any substitution will be done once. The only way I can solve the puzzle is to use expressions: match and preserve the anchored text and then use function [`substitute()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#substitute()) with flag `g`.

I managed with the following expression:

```
:s/\(^[^,]\+\)\(,\+\)\(.\+\)$/\=submatch(1) . submatch(2) . substitute(submatch(3), '[^,]', '', 'g')/
```

Let me split it in parts. Searching:

```
\(^[^,]\+\) — first, match any non-commas
\(,\+\) — any number of commas
\(.\+\)$ — all chars to the end of the string
```

Substituting:

```
\= — the substitution is an expression
```

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression

```
submatch(1) — replace with the first match (non-commas anchored with ^)
submatch(2) — replace with the second match (commas)
substitute(submatch(3), '[^,]', '', 'g') — replace in the rest of the string
```

The last call to `substitute()` is simple, it replaces all non-commas with empty strings.

PS. Tested in real `vim`, not vscode.

Comment: Tried s/^[^,]\+,[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+//g - does not work – I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: `submatch(1)` and `2` can be combined but that's a very minor improvement: `:s/\(^[^,]\+,\+\)\(.\+\)$/\=submatch(1) . substitute(submatch(2), '[^,]', '', 'g')/`